# Как сделать восходящее преобразование СПИСКА наследников к СПИСКУ базовых объектов?

Tags: c#, list, преобразование-типов

В наличии имеются 2 класса: родитель и наследник:

```
class Parent {}
class Heir : Parent {}
```

Да ещё и метод с 2 - мя параметрами: список объектов базового класса и объект базового класса:

```
public static void JustDoIt(List<Parent> parents, Parent parent)
{
  //...
}
```

Передаём методу список наследников и обычный объект наследника:

```
List<Heir> heirs = new List<Heir>();
Heir heir = new Heir();

JustDoIt(heirs, heir); // CS1503
```

И вот проблема: второй параметр преобразовался, а первый (список) - нет. Как это исправить? Как передать в метод список наследников?

Ошибка: CS1503: Аргумент 1: не удаётся преобразовать из "System.Collections.Generic.List<proj.Heir>" в "System.Collections.Generic.List<proj.Parent>".

Comment: `JustDoIt<T>(List<T> parents, T parent) where T : Parent`

Comment: Используйте обобщенный метод